# How to set MCLK in CS4270

Tags: i2s

I need to use the cs4270 for audio codec and I find that there are three bits to set the ratio select in Mode control part. I do not know how to set these three bits and what is the MCLK use for?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On page 4 of the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/76/CS4270_F1-39353.pdf) it says:

> **MCLK:** Master Clock (Input) - Clock for the delta-sigma modulator and
> the digital filters

There is no way we can know what requirements and specs your system has. You have to know what sampling frequency you need.

Comment: thank you for your reply! Can you explain the MCLK divide? I do not find any explain for that.
And what is the use of the MCLK Divider Configuration?

Comment: My guess:
Assume cs4270 operates at frequences from 4kHz to 54kHz, and the input clock frequencies is higher than cs4270's max operates frequences(54kHz), then I need to set the ratio select to make the input frequencies still between  4kHz to 54kHz?